# Why does the regular expression r'[a|(an)|(the)]+' detect 'h' and 'he' separately instead of 'the' as a whole?

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am trying to find 'a', 'an', 'the' in a given text. And the expression r'[a|(an)|(the)]+' recognizes only 'a' but not 'an' and 'the'.

```
nltk.re_show(r'[a|(an)|(the)]+', 'sdfkisdfjstdskfhdsklfjkhe an skfjkla')
```

This gives me the output

```
sdfkisdfjs{t}dskf{h}dsklfjk{h}{e} {a}{n} skfjkl{a}
```

I also tried

```
nltk.re_show(r'[a|<an>|<the>]+', 'sdfkisdfjstdskfhdsklfjkhe an skfjkla')
```

I get an output

```
sdfkisdfjs{t}dskf{h}dsklfjk{he} {an} skfjkl{a}
```

I don't understand why 'h' and 'he' are recognized.

What could be the right regular expression in this case to recognize 'a', 'an' and 'the' in a given text?

Comment: Use `r'the|an?'`

Comment: Can someone also explain why 'h' and 'he' are recognized for the regex in the question?

Comment: `[the]` matches a single char, either `t`, `h` or `e`.

Comment: Yes, but I used (the) and not [the].

Comment: Ok, `[(the)]` matches a single char, either a `(`, `t`, `h`, `e` or `)`.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Square and round braces don't have the same meaning. Square braces are used to specify "any one of the chars inside".

Note also that if you want to match "an", you don't want the capture to stop at "a", which means you have to reverse the order.

What you want instead of

```
[a|(an)|(the)]+
```

seems to be

```
(an|a|the)+
```

or maybe just

```
(an|a|the)
```

or (less readable)

```
(an?|the)
```

(yes, there are often many regexes for one problem)

Comment: Yes, that's right. but it still doesn't find 'an' and 'the'. I'm using re.findall() and nltk.re_show() to verify.

Comment: @MohitMotwani Denys's `(a|an|the)` regex will never match `an`. As I said in my comment, use `r'the|an?'`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, but the right solution is in my edited version

Comment: It is bad practice to have alternatives matching at the same location inside the string. `an?|the` or `the|an?` are best here.

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: `the|an|a`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jREUB0/3)

```
import re

text = 'sdfkisdfjstdskfhdsklfjkhe an skfjkla a dsda the dsathekoo'
array = re.findall(r'the|an|a', text)

print(array)
```

**Output**: `['an', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'the', 'a', 'the']`

Comment: It doesn't work for 'sdfkisdfjstdskfthedsklfjkhe an skfjkla'. Only recognizes 'an' but not 'the' in the long random first word above.

Comment: @Mohit Motwani Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, the following could be relevant to someone looking for an answer. My solution is

```
teststring='he was trying to snatch the token from a guy standing on an escalator in the mall'
re.findall(r'( the | a | an )', teststring)
[' the ', ' a ', ' an ', ' the ']
```

The leading and trailing spaces provide the unique sequence, which is required for the the search so that it can avoid the 'an' embedded inside the word 'standing' for example. You can strip the spaces off from the result set later on for further processing.

Thanks